# How can I get a view from an invisible tab?

Tags: android, tabs

I am designing an app for Android and I have a certain activity that uses a tabbed interface (3 tabs, one fragment per tab). So far, so good.

The problem is that, once the user has entered all the required information in the tabs and presses a button, I need to retrieve all that information. However, when I invoke `getViewById` to try and get a view that is in one of the not visible tabs, it returns `NULL`.

I have read several tutorials and SO threads explaining the tabbed interface, but none of them provided a working example; they all just created empty tabs.

How should I do this?

EDIT: I have three .xml files, one for each fragment/tab. This is the relevant code in the activity that handles the tabs:

```
public class SetupActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

    // Set up the action bar.
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


    /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    /** Defining tab listener */
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    /** Creating Android Tab */
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Partido").setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Equipo").setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Alineación").setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}


/**
 * This method is invoked when the user presses a button on tab number 3
 */
private void checkTeam() throws MatchNotReadyException {
    EditText teamName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTeamName); // this EditText is in tab number 1
    String name = teamName.getText().toString(); // I get a NullPointerException here

    if(name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        throw new MatchNotReadyException();
    }

    //some more actions
}
```

So, what do I have to do to get a valid reference to the `EditText`, instead of a `null`?

Comment: please post a code snippet to show how you are building the tabs and using the fragments

Comment: Ok, I have added some code to better explain the issue. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter as your base class for your adapter, it will delete the Fragments as you move along to many tabs.

Use a FragmentPagerAdapter as your base adapter. I am not sure if this is your problem because you don't have the adapter code, but I had a similar issue and that fixed it.